# How to pause an observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

How to really pause an rxjs observable?

I have the following code:

```
var pauser = new Rx.Subject();
var animation = new Rx.Subject();
var source = animation.pausableBuffered(pauser);

source
.subscribe(function(frame) {
    console.log('subscribe', frame);
    setTimeout(function() {
        source.resume();
    }, frame.duration);
    source.pause();
});

pauser.onNext(true);
console.log('start');
animation.onNext({ duration: 1000 });
animation.onNext({ duration: 2000 });
animation.onNext({ duration: 2000 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbvarga/8yvLhjhe/

I expect a **start** message in the console, right after a **subscribe**, than 1s break, than one **subscribe** message, than 2s break, and the last **subscribe**

but after the one second break I got the two last **subscribe** message immediately. Seems like I can pause the observable only once.

For those who are interested in what do I want to achieve: I want to have a queue of events, and I want to receive the next event, if some callback is called for the previous one (the event finished. now it's just a simple setTimeout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pausableBuffered keeps a buffer when paused *and drains the buffer when resume is called*. What you want looks more like a controlled observable, where you say `source.request(1)`.

See [the rxjs docs on backpressure](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/backpressure.md) for more info.

```js
var animation = new Rx.Subject();
var source = animation.controlled();

source
.subscribe(function(frame) {
    console.log('new event', frame);
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('after timeout', frame);
        source.request(1);
    }, frame.duration);
});

source.request(1);

animation.onNext({ duration: 1000 });
console.log('animation.onNext 1');
animation.onNext({ duration: 2000 });
console.log('animation.onNext 2');
animation.onNext({ duration: 3000 });
console.log('animation.onNext 3')
```